# .htaccess - multiple parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I've been looking, at all of the same questions in here like my own: How to rewrite multiple parameters? And figured how to do, but it doesn't seem to work out very well for me.

I wan't my link to look like this: link.dk/profil/2/overview

And my .htaccess looks like this:

```
#profil.php?id=? to profil/?
RewriteRule ^profil/(.*)$ profil.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^profil/(.*)/(.*)$ profil.php?id=$1&do=$2 [L]
```

It has to be able to access /profil/2 without the 3rd parameter. That's why I have 2 lines. I don't know if this is the right way to do it.

/profil/2 is working perfect and has been working for a while now. So no worries here. But I can't catch the 3rd parameter.

I'm also having those 2 in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Before the first two I wrote.

---

If I am using just the one with 2 parameters it's working. But then it's not working with /profil/2 ofc. And if I enter the url with profil.php?id=2&do=overview - I can access the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out my self:

```
RewriteRule ^profil/([^/]+)$ profil.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^profil/([^/]+)/([a-z]+)$ profil.php?id=$1&do=$2
```

.* seems abit unprecise and unstable :-)

Comment: `.*` is very well defined .  "`*`" is a greedy match -- that is it will match as long as possible.  For this type of match, you could use a non-greedy match `.*?` so for example `(.*?)/` means match any charcher sequence, but stop at the first /

Comment: alternatively you could change the order of the rules, but your solution is a lot more elegant.